# How to retype from (void *) to int in C++ without getting any warning when compiling with pedantic flag?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

I have `mutlithread` client-server application that communicates via `sockets`.
I create new thread with this construction:

```
 pthread_t thread;
 pthread_create(&thread, NULL, c->sendMessage, (void *) fd);
```

where `fd` is a ID of the connection and `c->sendMessage` is a function, that is called after a new thread is created and that handles this thread. Within this function I need to send some message via `send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags);`

so I get `sockfd` this way:

```
void * Client::sendMessage(void *threadid) {
   int sockfd = (int) threadid;
   // some more code here and in the end I send the data via send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags)
}
```

I compile with `-pedantic` flag and most of the compilers (mine including) don't throw any warning or error during the compilation. But some throw an error during compilation saying that this retyping from `void *` to `int` is unsafe and can cause `loose of precision`. I understand, that this is not a good solution and it should be done cleaner. But I can't find out how. Could anybody advice me any clean practice, how to retype ponter to int and avoid any warning during compilation?

Comment: The problem seems to be avoidable if you used `std::thread` at this point.

Comment: Yes, it may be the solution, how to avoid this problem, nevertheless the question is not, how to avoid it, but how to solve it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is problem to send pointer, instead of integer? Convert `int` to `void*`, or `void*` to `int`, it's not standard conformant solution.

```
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, c->sendMessage, new int(fd));

int* sockfd_ptr = (int*)threadid;
// some usage
delete sockfd_ptr;
```

Any pointer is convertible to `void*`, so it should works well. Don't forget to delete `threadid` in some place of your program.
May be it will better to create some class, where store reference/pointer.

Also, I can't understand, how you send member function into C function, it's not correct too.

Comment: Because I need to hold thread IDs in `vectors` and `maps` to be able to work with them further, so it's not just about sending a message. And yes, it may work just to hold the `pointers` within a `vector` as well, but I'm also curious how to fix this and why some compilers doesn't have any problem with that and some do.

Comment: `new int(fd)` is fine, but someone will need to `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

It's an extremely bad idea to cast from `int` to `void*` and then back to `int` because there are absolutely no guarantees in the C++ standard that those two types are the same size.

If you really must cast between an integer type and a pointer (which is not a very good idea, but sometimes there is no other choice), use **`intptr_t`** or **`uintptr_t`** instead of `int` since they are guaranteed to be the same size as a pointer. This way you won't get any warning.

As a side note, legacy C casts like you're doing are frowned upon in C++ because you can't be sure what they are doing under the hood (it could be a `static_cast` or a `reinterpret_cast`, who knows?). Prefer using proper C++ casts, namely `reinterpret_cast` in your case.

Comment: For me the question implies that type of `fd` is externally defined without choice

Comment: @BalogPal: ah right, I missed that. But then I'm afraid there's no way to properly cast between them. ForEveR's solution or PlasmaHH 's comment may be the correct ones then.

Comment: `pthread_create` has a fixed signature, so no option to change that. But the questioner might try casting `int` to `intptr_tv and then to `void*`.

Comment: @WernerHenze: Yes, I only missed the part of the question where the type of `fd` is out of control. My answer was indeed to address the case where one *must* cast to and from `void*` like with `pthread_create`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like `static_assert(sizeof(fd) <= sizeof(void*), "problem")`, and rely on documentation of your implementation that reinterpret_cast will round-trip in this situation.